# the circuit of active probe using FET trace CRO

Tags: oscilloscope, fet

pls suggest the circuit of active probe using FET trace CRO.

Comment: If you can't be bothered to Google "active scope probe", I'm not sure there's much hope for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is from Troubleshooting Analog Circuits by Bob Pease. He claims 90MHz and Cin < 1pF:

[image]

Comment: I've just uploaded that to imgur because Stack Exchange have an arrangement where they are kept long term, whereas Dropbox links sometimes disappear. Although it might be worth adding some extra description as text so it's more searchable.

Comment: Hi @PeterJ,  I'm new here.  Do I have to add the text?  Or can you?  JFET active 'scope probe.. or something like that.  (I just happened to have the pic in my dropbox, and I thought I'd share

Comment: Hi @George, you can press the edit button to make any additions. I was just thinking maybe just type up a bit of a summary of how it works from the book, probably best to just summarise in your own words a bit rather than copy too much verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

An immensely valuable resource is available via Google images.
Everyone know that you can search for things on Google.
Fewer people realise what you get when you repeat the same search using Google images.

The "a picture is worth 1000 words" adage tends to apply. 
Now, instead of reading text and trying to determine relevance, you can look at many pictures very rapidly and click on those which appear relevant visually.
Every picture is linked to a web page and, even if many do not cover what they may at first appear to, this still (usually) produces many good results immensely rapidly via the pictures.

Copying your exact question text into Google images, I used

- circuit of active probe using FET trace CRO

To give [this result](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=circuit+of+active+probe+using+FET+trace+CRO&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=aTjJU9_fMtLt8AXPqIHwCw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1280&bih=688)

This is just a small part of the result. While not all are relevant, many are:

[image]

Try it. You'll like it.

---

Clicking on a few of those images which looked useful gave these results.
Some will be relevant to your query. There are many more.

http://edn.com/design/other/4383070/Oscilloscope-active-probe

[Is this a good design & layout of an active differential 'scope probe?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29363/is-this-a-good-design-layout-of-an-active-differential-scope-probe)

http://www.eng.yale.edu/ee-labs/morse/probe/probe3.htm

http://www.seekic.com/blog/project_solutions/2011/08/03/Poor_Man%E2%80%99s_1_GHz_Active_Probe__DIY_Saves_a_Pretty_Penny_%EF%BC%881%EF%BC%89.html

http://www.audiokarma.org/forums/showthread.php?t=216243

http://oliverbetz.de/pages/Artikel/Simple-High-Impedance-Probe